# Remembering a users place in the form using PHP sessions

Tags: php, forms, session, session-cookies

I have made a short quiz containing of 4 yes/no questions, what I am trying to is make it so that if the user closes the web page when they are on the second question for example, then when they re-open the page (up to 30 days later) they will be taken to the same question they left on. Below is some of the code I have got so far.

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(2592000); //Sets cookie to last for 30 days
session_start();
?>
```

This is the code for the questions

```
//Variables for functions
 $number;
 $creature2;
 $creature3;
 //Function for showing questions 2 to 7
  function showquestion($number) {

      echo "<div class='questions'><form method ='GET' action='Creatures.php'>
     <input type='submit' name='answer$number' value='Yes' class='buttons' />
     <input type='submit' name='answer$number' value='No' class='buttons' />
     </form></div>";
 }

  //Function for showing questions 8 to 15
  function showanswer($creature2,$creature3) {
      echo "<div class='questions'><form method ='GET' action='Creatures.php'>
     <button type='submit' name='final' value='$creature2' class='buttons'> Yes </button>
     <button type='submit' name='final' value='$creature3' class='buttons'> No </button>
     </form></div>";
 }
//If start button has not been pressed, display nothing
if (!isset($_POST['start'])){

} //If start button has been pressed, display questions
else{ 
echo $firstquestion;
     echo "<div class='questions'><form method ='GET' action='Creatures.php'>
     <input type='submit' name='yes1' value='Yes' class='buttons' />
     <input type='submit' name='no1' value='No' class='buttons' />
     </form></div>";
}
//Question 2
if ($_GET['yes1']) //If answer to Q1 is yes then display this
{
echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[0][0]}</p></div>";
showquestion(1);
}

//Question 3
if ($_GET['no1']) 
{
echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[0][1]}</p></div>"; //If answer to Q1 is no then display this
showquestion(2);
}

//Questions 4 and 5
switch($_GET['answer1']) //If Question 2 is yes, do this
{
case 'Yes': echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[1][0]}</p></div>";
showquestion(3);
break;
case 'No': echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[1][1]}</p></div>";
showquestion(4);
}

//Questions 6 and 7
switch($_GET['answer2']) //If Question 3 is yes, do this
{
case 'Yes': echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[1][2]}</p></div>";
showquestion(5);
break;
case 'No': echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[1][3]}</p></div>";
showquestion(6);
}

//Questions 8 and 9
switch($_GET['answer3']) 
{
case 'Yes': echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[2][0]}</p></div>";
showanswer('Eagle','Parrot');
break;
case 'No': echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[2][1]}</p></div>";
showanswer('Ostrich','Turkey_(bird)');
}

//Questions 10 and 11
switch($_GET['answer4']) 
{
case 'Yes': echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[2][2]}</p></div>";
showanswer('Grasshopper','Ant');
break;
case 'No': echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[2][3]}</p></div>";
showanswer('Gorilla','Tiger');
}

//Questions 12 and 13
switch($_GET['answer5']) 
{
case 'Yes': echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[3][0]}</p></div>";
showanswer('Penguin','Goose');
break;
case 'No': echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[3][1]}</p></div>";
showanswer('Frog','Salamander');
}

//Questions 14 and 15
switch($_GET['answer6']) 
{
case 'Yes': echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[3][2]}</p></div>";
showanswer('Octopus','Jellyfish');
break;
case 'No': echo "<div class='questions'><p>{$questions[3][3]}</p></div>";
showanswer('Goldfish','Eel');
}
```

I know this is possible as I have seen other people do it before. The quiz is here [My Quiz](http://s504518.brunelweb.net/Creatures.php)

Comment: When the user answers a question set a cookie with that question number. Then on question 1 check for that cookie and advance to that question if necessary.

Comment: Why don't you save the current url into the session? (lets say http://example.com/questions?question=2&answer=no or however you structure them) and then when the user comes into the site you redirect to that url?

If you also store 'answers-id' = '124828201' in the session and save the answers to the DB every time you can then group all the questions together. Instead of the db you could also store it all in the session of course. I would go with a nested array in that case:
$_SESSION['questions'][1] = 'no'... etc

Comment: Don't forget to change your session settings - you might be overriding the cookie expiry default time, but PHP will still nuke the session files on its own schedule.